# How do i use a function that returns multiple values for variables and parse them to a class?

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone explain how to modify this program so the multiple results are parsed to the do class.

doclass.py

```
class do:
    def __init__(self, a1, b2, c3):
        self.a = a1
        self.b = b2
        self.c = c3

    def wahh(self):
        print(self.a*10)
        print(self.b*40)
        print(self.c*23)

    def main(self):
        self.wahh()
```

test.py

```
from doclass import do
blah = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def forloop():
    for num in blah:
        a1 = 10 * num
        b2 = 100 * num
        c3 = 1000 * num

        return a1, b2, c3


a,b,c = forloop()
stuff = do(a,b,c) 
stuff.main()
```

Comment: What is the expected output? I am afraid your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is your `forloop` function, which returns inside of a `for` loop: it means it will stop that loop in the first iteration with `num = 1`. You may have expected to get all the calculated values from the `blah` list. For that purpose you can replace the `return` with `yield` which will make from your function a `generator function`. Then you can loop this generator to produce all intended values.

```py
def forloop(data):
    for num in data:
        a1 = 10 * num
        b2 = 100 * num
        c3 = 1000 * num

        yield a1, b2, c3

for a,b,c in forloop(blah):
    stuff = do(a,b,c)
    stuff.main()
```